# Using Linux Ubuntu 16.04 on Macbook Pro 2016

Tags: macbook-pro

Current Specs:

Macbook Pro 2016 Touch Bar 15"

- 2.6GHz quad-core Intel Core i7, Turbo Boost up to 3.5GHz, with 6MB shared L3 cache
- 16GB of 2133MHz LPDDR3 onboard memory
- Radeon Pro 450 with 2GB of GDDR5 memory and automatic graphics switching
  Intel HD Graphics 530

Installed:

- Linux 16.04.1 LTS (have to use this for my class assignment and not the 16.10)
- Assigned 8GB of RAM & 20GB of Fixed size of storage
- Assigned 4 CPU
- Enabled Nested Paging
- Assigned 64 MB for Video Memory

Problem:

- Laggy interface
  such as when I tried to move the file explorer, its moving really slow. Basically I have to keep the screen small to use it. If I go full screen or half of the screen, it becomes really laggy.

I have looked up a lot of different way to help make it faster but it just didnt work. Any advice is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Your title says 16.10, your description says 16.04. Which are you using?

Comment: Sorry. 16.04. Thank you for that error!

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu as a dual-boot setup with OS X, or are you using it in virtual machine software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running Ubuntu in a VM, it may be that you simply need to a) upgrade your AMD drivers through Mac, or b) wait for an update.

As the AMD Radeon Pro 450 is Apple proprietary, drivers have been conflicting and known to conflict with MacOS at the moment, and that most likely stretches to the VM.

3D acceleration may also not be enabled. Be sure to enable that.

Comment: @NickWeinberg Ah, didn't think of that.

Comment: upgrade the AMD drive? do i go to the AMD website to look for the AMD driver?

i have tried enabling 3D acceleration, it's still the same. Should i keep it on and left it off then?

Comment: @SwiftQuestions Mac produces their own drivers. Your issue is most likely AMD driver-related, and therefore not an issue with Ubuntu. If my question helped please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same equipment and the same happened to me. Fix it by activating the 3D acceleration in the configurations of the virtualbox.